# SerializeObject is returning an empty object

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonconvert

JsonConvert.SerializeObject is returning an empty object

I can serialize a generic object, and I can serialize this object in a different assembly.  I've verified the properties are public and also explicitly marked with json tags.  No exception is being thrown by Newtonsoft.Json.  Relevant version Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.2, installed via nuget.

The test is failing because the expected call and actual call are different. The actual call (not pasted) is what I expect, but the Json serializes gives an empty object in the test.

`logger.Verify(m => m.LogUsage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_svc), "AddService", string.Empty, false), Times.Once());`

UPDATE: I tried adding the following test and it still is serializing to an empty object, despite _svc being defined correctly (I can tell by setting a breakpoint and inspecting it.)

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestUnableToSerialize()
    {
      string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_svc);

      Assert.AreEqual(string.Empty, result);
    }
```

```
  [TestClass]
  public class ServiceDirectoryTests
  {
    private Service _defaultSvc;
    private ServiceInfoResponse _defaultSvcInfo;
    private Mock<ILogger> logger;
    private ILogger _logger;
    public Service _svc;
    private ServiceInfoResponse _svcInfo;
    private List<string> _serviceMonikers;
    private string _serialized;

    [TestInitialize()]
    public void Initialize()
    {
      logger = new Mock<ILogger>();
      _logger = logger.Object;

      _defaultSvcInfo = new ServiceInfoResponse()
      {
        endpoint = "default endpoint",
        environment_id = string.Empty,
        id = "defaultId",
        iso_a2_country_code = "UK",
        moniker = "Account",
        tenant_moniker = "default",
        url_selection_scheme = UrlSelectionScheme.ServiceDefault
      };

      _defaultSvc = new Service(_defaultSvcInfo);

      _svcInfo = new ServiceInfoResponse()
      {
        endpoint = "service endpoint",
        environment_id = string.Empty,
        id = "nonDefaultId",
        iso_a2_country_code = "UK",
        moniker = "Account",
        tenant_moniker = "ztorstrick",
        url_selection_scheme = UrlSelectionScheme.ServiceDefault
      };

      _svc = new Service(_svcInfo);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task AddServiceDefaultReturned()
    {
      Mock<IServiceDirectory> mockClient = new Mock<IServiceDirectory>();
      mockClient.Setup(x => x.CreateService(
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>()
      ))
      .ReturnsAsync(_defaultSvcInfo);

      ServiceDirectory svc = new ServiceDirectory(mockClient.Object, _logger);

      Service result = await svc.AddService(_svc, "");
      Assert.AreEqual(_defaultSvc.Endpoint, result.Default);
      Assert.AreEqual(result.Default, result.Endpoint);
      Assert.AreEqual(_defaultSvc.EnvironmentId, result.EnvironmentId);
      Assert.AreEqual(string.Empty, result.Id);
      Assert.AreEqual(_defaultSvc.IsoA2CountryCode, result.IsoA2CountryCode);
      Assert.AreEqual(_defaultSvc.Moniker, result.Moniker);
      Assert.AreEqual(_defaultSvc.ServiceName, result.ServiceName);
      Assert.AreEqual(_defaultSvc.TenantMoniker, result.TenantMoniker);
      Assert.AreEqual("ServiceDefault", result.UrlSelectionScheme);

      logger.Verify(m => m.LogUsage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_svc), "AddService", string.Empty, false), Times.Once());
    }
  }

  public class Service : PropertyChangedBase
  {
    #region " Private Variables "

    private string _default;
    private string _endpoint;
    private string _environmentId;
    private string _id;
    private bool _isSelected;
    private string _isoA2CountryCode;
    private string _moniker;
    private string _serviceName;
    private string _tenantMoniker;
    private string _urlSelectionScheme;
    private string _version;

    #endregion

    #region "Constructors"

    public Service()
    {
      Id         = string.Empty;
      IsDirty    = false;
      IsSelected = false;
    }

    public Service(Service service)
    {
      if (service == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(); }

      Default            = service.Default;
      Endpoint           = service.Endpoint;
      EnvironmentId      = service.EnvironmentId;
      Id                 = service.Id;
      IsDirty            = service.IsDirty;
      IsoA2CountryCode   = service.IsoA2CountryCode;
      IsSelected         = service.IsSelected;
      Moniker            = service.Moniker;
      ServiceName        = service.ServiceName;
      TenantMoniker      = service.TenantMoniker;
      UrlSelectionScheme = service.UrlSelectionScheme;

      // DO NOT keep Ids for default services, to prevent accidental editing and deletion
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(service.TenantMoniker) ||
         string.Equals(service.TenantMoniker, "default", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
      {
        Id = string.Empty;
      }
    }

    public Service(ServiceInfoResponse response)
    {
      if (response == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(); }

      IsDirty            = false;
      Endpoint           = response.endpoint;
      EnvironmentId      = response.environment_id;
      Id                 = response.id;
      IsoA2CountryCode   = response.iso_a2_country_code;
      IsSelected         = false;
      Moniker            = response.moniker;
      ServiceName        = response.service_name;
      TenantMoniker      = response.tenant_moniker;
      UrlSelectionScheme = response.url_selection_scheme.ToString();

      // DO NOT keep Ids for default services, to prevent accidental editing and deletion
      if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.tenant_moniker) || 
         string.Equals(response.tenant_moniker, "default", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
      {
        Id = string.Empty;
      }
    }

    #endregion

    #region "Properties"

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Default
    {
      get { return _default; }

      set
      {
        if (_default != value)
        {
          _default = value;
          NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Default);
        }
      }
    }

    [JsonProperty("endpoint")]
    public string Endpoint
    {
      get { return _endpoint; }

      set
      {
        if (_endpoint != value)
        {
          _endpoint = value;
          NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Endpoint);
        }
      }
    }

    [JsonProperty("environment_id")]
    public string EnvironmentId
    {
      get { return _environmentId; }

      set
      {
        if (_environmentId != value)
        {
          _environmentId = value;
          NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => EnvironmentId);
        }
      }
    }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id
    {
      get { return _id; }

      set
      {
        if (_id != value)
        {
          _id = value;
          NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Id);
          NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsDefault);
        }
      }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsDefault
    {
      get
      {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id);
      }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsDirty { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
      get { return _isSelected; }

      set
      {
        if (_isSelected != value)
        {
          _isSelected = value;
          NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsSelected);
        }
      }
    }

    [JsonProperty("iso_a2_country_code")]
    public string IsoA2CountryCode
    {
      get { return _isoA2CountryCode; }

      set
      {
        if (_isoA2CountryCode != value)
        {
          _isoA2CountryCode = value;
          NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsoA2CountryCode);
        }
      }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool MatchesDefault { get { return string.Equals(Endpoint, Default, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase); } }

    [JsonProperty("moniker")]
    public string Moniker
    {
      get { return _moniker; }

      set
      {
        if (_moniker != value)
        {
          _moniker = value;
          NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Moniker);
        }
      }
    }

    [JsonProperty("service_name")]
    public string ServiceName
    {
      get { return _serviceName; }

      set
      {
        if (_serviceName != value)
        {
          _serviceName = value;
          NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ServiceName);
        }
      }
    }

    [JsonProperty("tenant_moniker")]
    public string TenantMoniker
    {
      get { return _tenantMoniker; }

      set
      {
        if (_tenantMoniker != value)
        {
          _tenantMoniker = value;
          NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TenantMoniker);
        }
      }
    }

    [JsonProperty("url_selection_scheme")]
    public string UrlSelectionScheme
    {
      get { return _urlSelectionScheme; }

      set
      {
        if (_urlSelectionScheme != value)
        {
          _urlSelectionScheme = value;
          NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => UrlSelectionScheme);
        }
      }
    }

    [JsonProperty("version")]
    public string Version
    {
      get { return _version; }

      set
      {
        if (_version != value)
        {
          _version = value;
          NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Version);
        }
      }
    }

    #endregion
  }
```

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?  You're not using [tag:xamarin-live-player] are you?

Comment: I don't know what xamarin-live-player is, but I doubt I'm using it. This is a wpf project and uses proprietary libraries that I can't share, so a reproducible example is a problem.  I tried to share all the relevant bits.

Comment: I tried to create a console project with just the relevant pieces but I can't reproduce it that way.  I'll keep trying to track down what breaks it, but hopefully someone can point out something silly that I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a NuGet reference to Newtonsoft.Json in my unit test project. I removed that, rebuilt, and now it works. The only thing I can think is there were different versions of Json floating around (this has happened to me before) and it was breaking something.